# QML Preload Font

Tags: fonts, qml, preload

I have a font with glyphicons that I want to use in my QML source. I load the font with:

```
FontLoader {
    id: glyphs
    source: "fonts/glyphicons.ttf"
}
```

Then show a glyphicon with:

```
Text {
    font.family: glyphs.name
    text: "\ue80a"
}
```

The problem is that sometimes the Text elements will load before the FontLoader finishes to load the font file and I just see the blank squares instead of the icons.

I also tried:

```
Text {
    visible: glyphs.status == FontLoader.Ready ? true : false
    font.family: glyphs.name
    text: "\ue80a"
}
```

But that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Yeah, it look a bug. I also cannot trigger `onStateChanged` while loading nor from web nor from local system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an easy fix for this.

```
FontLoader {
    id: glyphs
    source: "fonts/glyphicons.ttf"
}
Text {
    font.family: glyphs.name
    text: glyphs.status == FontLoader.Ready ? "\ue80a" : ""
}
```

The problem was that the character was rendered before the font was loaded. If we just refresh the text after `FontLoader.Ready` is triggered, it will show correctly.

In the example above, the glyphicon will only show after the font was loaded.